# Postback no funciona en ASP net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un campo en donde el usuario al colocar su DNI se llenará automáticamente los otros campos. El problema es que no llega a traer los datos del usuario y no me muestra ningún error.

**Clase Interesado**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FormularioCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsInteresado
    {
        public string ID_Inter { get; set; }
        public string dni_Inter { get; set; }
        public string apePat_Inter { get; set; }
        public string apeMat_Inter { get; set; }
        public string nombres_Inter { get; set; }
        public string fecha_nac_Inter { get; set; }
        public string edad_Inter { get; set; }
        public string sexo_Inter { get; set; }
        public string correo_Inter { get; set; }
        public string telefono_Inter { get; set; }
        public string direccion_Inter { get; set; }
        public string depar_Inter { get; set; }
        public string provin_Inter { get; set; }
        public string dist_Inter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostBackAjax(string campo_DNI_JSON)
    {

        ServicesReniec.sConsultaDNISoapClient consultaDNI = new ServicesReniec.sConsultaDNISoapClient();
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
        resultado = consultaDNI.Consulta("JVEGA", campo_DNI_JSON);
        string ape_pat = "";
        string ape_mat = "";
        string nombres = "";
        string fech_nac = "";

        string edad = "";
        string sexo = "";
        string correo = "";
        string telefono = "";
        string direccion = "";

        string departamento = "";
        string provincia = "";
        string distrito = "";

        string ubigeo = "";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string R in resultado)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    if ((R.Substring(0, 4) != "0000"))
                    {
                        //limpiarFormulario();
                        return Json(new ClsInteresado());
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    ape_pat = R;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ape_mat = R;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    nombres = R;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (R.Equals(" "))
                    {
                        departamento = "CALLAO";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        departamento = R;
                    }

                    break;
                case 9:
                    provincia = R;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    distrito = R;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    direccion = R;
                    break;
                case 21:
                    fech_nac = R;
                    break;
            }
            i++;

        }

        ClsInteresado interesado = new ClsInteresado
        {
            apePat_Inter = ape_pat,
            apeMat_Inter = ape_mat,
            nombres_Inter = nombres,
            fecha_nac_Inter = fech_nac,
            edad_Inter = edad,
            sexo_Inter = sexo,
            correo_Inter = correo,
            telefono_Inter = telefono,
            direccion_Inter = direccion,
            depar_Inter = departamento,
            provin_Inter = provincia,
            dist_Inter = distrito
        };

        return Json(interesado);
    }
```

**Vista Interesado**

```
@model FormularioCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CrearInteresado";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<h2>CrearInteresado</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClsInteresado</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dni_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dni_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_dni", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dni_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apePat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apePat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_apeMat", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_nombres", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombres_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_fechNac", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nac_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.edad_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.edad_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_edad", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.edad_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correo_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correo_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_correo", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_telefono", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_direccion", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direccion_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depar_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.depar_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_departamento", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depar_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.provin_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.provin_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_provincia", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.provin_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dist_Inter, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dist_Inter, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "campo_distrito", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dist_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        let dni = $('#campo_dni');
        let apePat = $('#campo_apePat');
        let apeMat = $('#campo_apeMat');
        let nombres = $('#campo_nombres');
        let fechNac = $('#campo_fechNac');
        let edad = $('#campo_edad');
        let sexo = $('#campo_sexo');
        let correo = $('#campo_correo');
        let telefono = $('#campo_telefono');
        let direccion = $('#campo_direccion');
        let departamento = $('#campo_departamento');
        let provincia = $('#campo_provincia');
        let distrito = $('#campo_distrito');

        function formPost() {

            let dniValor = dni.val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Charlas/PostBackAjax",
                data: "{ campoDniJSON: 'dniValor'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (rpta) {
                    apePat.val(rpta.apePat_Inter);
                    apeMat.val(rpta.apeMat_Inter);
                    nombres.val(rpta.nombres_Inter);
                    fechNac.val(rpta.fecha_nac_Inter);
                    edad.val(rpta.edad_Inter);
                    sexo.val(rpta.sexo_Inter);
                    correo.val(rpta.correo_Inter);
                    telefono.val(rpta.telefono_Inter);
                    direccion.val(rpta.direccion_Inter);
                    departamento.val(rpta.depar_Inter);
                    provincia.val(rpta.provin_Inter);
                    distrito.val(rpta.dist_Inter);
                }
            });
        }

        $('#campo_dni').focusout(function () {
            formPost();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Considera implementar las [respuestas](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de forma correcta con ajax, si ocurre algún error no sabrás que pasó ya que sólo implementas el success.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba entre comillas simples:

```
data: { 'campo_DNI_JSON': dni }
```

Comment: Ahora me aparece un error internal server 500

Comment: prueba detener y volver a iniciar, deberia indicar el error, al menos si se se corre local